# Openni_launch cannot subscribe both to depth_registered and rgb

Tags: ros, openni, openni-launch, openni.launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ros-hydro-openni-launch to my Odroid-U3. When I ran

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

it successfully streams as I can see the topics send average at 30 fps via the command

```
rostopic hz /camera/rgb/image_rect_color
```

However, once I subscribe also to

```
rostopic hz /camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw
```

Both of the subscribers do not receive any more images as shown below..

Is this a bug? I also downloaded the latest commit of openni_launch and openni_camera in the github. But it was still the same... But they DO WORK alone. But subscribing to both of them fails....

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185566/openni_launch-cannot-subscribe-both-to-depth_registered-and-rgb/) by [Xegara](https://answers.ros.org/users/14401/xegara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2014-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at Openni.launch shows:

```
  <!-- Use OpenNI's factory-calibrated depth->RGB registration? -->
  <arg name="depth_registration" default="false" />
```

meaning you need to instead run

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch depth_registration:=true
```

Although you are reporting that depth_registration works without setting that argument to be true, which is odd. Regardless maybe this will fix the issue? worth a shot...

---

Originally posted by [ahubers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10876/ahubers/) with karma: 301 on 2014-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1